# RailsでDBへの接続確認する方法を教えてください。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, rubymine

Ruby on Railsで開発をしています。
rails g modelコマンドを利用してmigrateファイル、modelなど一気に生成しました。
その後、modelの名前だけを利用する必要があり、変更しましたが、こうした場合、modelとDBのTableの名前が合わないようになります。
それで、modelからTableへの連結ができるのかが心配で接続のテストがしたいんですが、どうテストできれば教えてください。できればサンプルのコードがあれば嬉しいです。
そもそもmodelとmigrateファイルなどはどのような関係がありますか？同じ名前で生成される理由も教えていただければと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Railsでは、モデル名からテーブル名を判断して接続しています。
モデル名はテーブル名の単数形のキャメルケースになります。
例えば、 `user_permissions` というテーブルがあった場合、モデルは `UserPermission` となります。

モデル名とテーブル名が一致していない場合、モデルに明示的にテーブル名を設定する必要があります。
`UserPermission` というモデルで `permissions` というテーブル名を使いたい場合、以下のようにモデルに書きます。

```
def UserPermission < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'permissions'
end
```

接続のテストですが、 `rails console` を使うと楽です。
railsのプロジェクトのディレクトリで、 `rails c` と打つとコンソールが起動しますので、そこでテストをしてください。
`UserPermission` に接続する場合は以下の様なかたちで確認できます。

```
$ rails c
[1] pry(main)> UserPermission.all
```